# where clause inside when condition in query builder, saying undefined variable

Tags: laravel-5.7, laravel-query-builder

I have a strange problem, I am making a conditional query with values stored in different variables and passing them to where clause. That where clause simply not accepting values and keep on saying undefined variable in very first condition. To understand it I just cut it to one condition and make it simple to get easy answers.

**Error:** `ErrorException: Undefined variable: col_name in file E:\xampp\htdocs\coder\app\Http\Controllers\a26_gets\a26_gets_ctrl.php on line 97`

**Code:**

```
$this->tableName = 'mytable';
$col_name = 'first_name';
$value = 'danny';

$tableData = DB::table($this->tableName)
    ->when($value, function ($query, $value) {
        return $query->where($col_name, $value);
    })->paginate(1);

print_r($tableData);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `$col_name` to the scope of the conditional query...

```
$this->tableName = 'mytable';
$col_name = 'first_name';
$value = 'danny';

$tableData = DB::table($this->tableName)
    ->when($value, function ($query, $value) use ($col_name) {
        return $query->where($col_name, $value);
    })->paginate(1);

print_r($tableData);
```